# HTML content without scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css

I'm developing an application which shows books content in browser. User could read the book in browser just like in a desktop application book reader such as mobile pocket reader.

For example, browser shows no scroll bars and HTML content is separated into different pages.

In browser, when I view a page in print version (e.g press `ctrl` + `P`), I see that browser separates HTML content into different pages which acts just like wanted behavior.

How could I reproduce that function in normal web version?

Comment: With quite a bit of difficulty, I would imagine. I believe this question amounts to "Do this complicated thing for me. Please."

StackOverflow is not that sort of site. Instead, show us what you have tried, what didn't work, etc.

Comment: One possibility: render the page as a PDF (either in the browser or on the server) and display that PDF. Built-in page-browsing functionality.

Comment: @GregL: I'm not asking for a specific implementation, just for the solution then I could do it on my own.

Comment: The hard part would be to split the content into multiple `<div>`s, each the height of the viewport, and then you could use one of [these plugins](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/5-free-jquery-page-flip-plugins-for-book-like-interfaces/).

Comment: @GregL Thanks for your suggestion. Also, I'm interested in how browser could split HTML content into pages and calculate exactly how many pages there are when we hit ctrl+p? If we know the mechanism we could implement it.